# Feasibility of controlling two or more NAS via iSCSI

Tags: network-attached-storage, iscsi

We currently run a two-year-old Iomega StorCenter ix2-200 through Windows iSCSI initiator on a Dell Optiplex 745. Meanwhile, we have two Seagate BlackArmor 440's running independently through Ethernet ports.

Is it possible to add the BlackArmors to the current iSCSI setup. If so, will the BlackArmors need to be reformatted and thus erase their current files? Will throughput decrease?

Please be gentle as I'm new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, what you intend to do is possible since BlackArmor can provide an iSCSI target. Yet you should be aware that there is *always* a risk of loosing data in applying any modifications to your storage setup.

First BlackArmor user manual does not mention iSCSI at all. You would have to search Seagate knowledgebase for "*blackarmor iscsi*". There is this [article](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/219631en) on setting up an iSCSI target.

You would have to ensure that the firmware on your BlackArmor is at least v. 4000.1211.

Also note that disconnecting an operational iSCSI volume may lead to inconsistencies in the underlying filesystem and result in a loss of data.

All warnings being made, you should be fine with your plan.

Comment: Actually discovered a newer firmware 4000.1311 provides an iSCSI Manager. Have enabled it, backed up the files and moving forward. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've done everything up to 8:14 in this video - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/Video/ff710316. My Disk3 has Unknown under it. When it tell it to Initialize Disk3 using GPT (because they are 3TB disks) a Virtual Disk Manager error pops up - "The drive cannot find the sector requested." <br> <br>What are my options to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

iSCSI is a SAN protocol
The BlackArmor devices are NAS devices.

NAs and SAN are not the same thing, or even very close.

Comment: Actually BlackArmor provides an iSCSI target. See this [FAQ article](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/219631en) and [another](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/219651en).